# Firebase lazy load

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to lazy load firebase items to later on load more of them whenever user reaches end of div container. When i remove `.endAt()` and `.startAt()` i'm receiving the 15 items though they are not beeing incremented and it's stuck at these 15 items.

When i keep `.endAt()` and `.startAt()` i'm receiving firebase warning
`Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "title" at /items` even though `.indexOn` is set. I'm confused by that warning. Thanks in advance for any help.

Firebase structure

```
{
  "items" : {
    "-Kk6aHXIyR15XiYh65Ht" : {
      "author" : "joe", 
      "title" : "Product 1"
    },
    "-Kk6aMQlh6_E3CJt_Pnq" : {
      "author" : "joe",
      "title" : "Product 2"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "RG9JSm8cUndpjMfZiN6c657DMIt2" : {
      "items" : {
        "-Kk6aHZs5xyOWM2fHiPV" : "-Kk6aHXIyR15XiYh65Ht",
        "-Kk6aMTJiLSF-RB3CZ-2" : "-Kk6aMQkw5bLQst81ft7"
      },
      "uid" : "RG9JSm8cUndpjMfZiN6c657DMIt2",
      "username" : "joe"
    }
  }
}
```

Security rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,  
    ".write": "auth != null",  
    "users":{
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        "items":{
          ".indexOn": "title",
          "$itemId": {
            "title": {".validate": "...}
            "type": {".validate": "...}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Code structure for lazy load

```
let _start = 0,
    _end = 14,
    _n = 15;

function lazyLoadItems(){
  firebase.database().ref('items')
        .orderByChild('title')
        .startAt(_start)
        .endAt(_end)
        .limitToFirst(_n)
        .on("child_added", snapshot=> console.log(snapshot.val()));
  _start += _n;
  _end += _n;
}
```

Comment: You're querying `/items`, while you added an index to `/users/$uid/items`.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, though I want to list all items from all users, so querying `/users/$uid/items` without `uid` won't do the job. And adding `.indexOn('items')` in `"rules"` doesn't make sense. Could it be badly structured rules then?

Comment: That's impossible to say with what you shared. A minimal snippet of the JSON might help. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Where `items` === `decks`. https://pastebin.com/wskVaNPy

Comment: I added the JSON to the question. But there is no `/items` in there. Please provide a single [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link on why this is a more efficient way to get help than the back-and-forth we've been having).

Comment: Hmm should be fine as for now unless i'm misinterpreting `/item` in `security rules`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how Firebase queries work. It's easiest to see if you use hard-coded values:

```
firebase.database().ref('items')
    .orderByChild('title')
    .startAt(0)
    .endAt(14)
    .limitToFirst(15)
```

There is no item with `title=0` or `title=14`, so the query doesn't match anything.

Firebase Database queries match on the value of the property you order on. So when you order by `title` the values you specify in `startAt` and `endAt` must be titles. E.g.

```
ref.child('items')
   .orderByChild('title')
   .startAt("Product 1")
   .endAt("Product 1")
   .limitToFirst(15)
   .on("child_added", function(snapshot) { console.log(snapshot.val()); });
```

See for the working sample of this: http://jsbin.com/hamezu/edit?js,console

To implement pagination, you'll have to remember the last item of the previous page and pass that in to the next call: `startAt(titleOfLastItemOnPreviousPage, keyOfLastItemOnPreviousPage)`.

Comment: Ooooh that makes sense now. Still new to NoSQL world though that clarifies everything!

Answer (score 0):

startAfter is the last element

each time you have to send the last element:

```
const lastAlert = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1]
```

here an example:

```
export const fetchAlerts = (createdForId, startAfter) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase
    let query = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('alerts')
      .where('generated_for.uid', '==', createdForId)
      .where('read', '==', false)
      .orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
      .limit(25)
    if (startAfter) {
      query = query.startAfter(startAfter)
    }

    query
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        const lastAlert = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1]
        const alerts = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          ...doc.data(),
          uid: doc.id,
        }))
        resolve(alerts)
        resolve({ alerts, lastAlert })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message)
```