# Firebase - Query based on partitioned offset logic

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, lazy-loading, angularfire2

I'm creating a chat app in Angular 4 which stores and reads messages in and from the Firebase database.

I've written a query to retrieve only the latest 10 messages of that specific conversation.

```
this.messages = this.db.list('messages/' + conversationId, { query: { limitToLast: 10 } });
```

*db: AngularFireDatabase, messages: FirebaseListObservable*

Now I want to retrieve the 10 older messages when somene presses the 'more' button (or scrolls to the top) and I'm having difficulties writing a query for this.

This is what I tried:

```
this.messages = this.db.list('messages/' + conversationId, { query: { orderbyChild: 'id', startAt: start, limitToLast: 10 } });
```

*'start' here is an id like '-KovtCl4hEUPR2LfQfpc', which is the id of the oldest message in the this.messages FirebaseListObservable. I've also tried to manually pass this ID as string to the method that executes the query above.*

Trying to do it as described here:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43969460/5437768
2. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query
3. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data

The last query gives me 0 results.

**Firebase layout**

/messages/conversationId/messageId/{message}

```
"messages": {
    "-k32b": {
        "-kT3d": {
            "content": "Hello World!",
            "id" : "-kT3d"
        },
        "-kT4c": {
            "content": "How are you World?",
            "id" : "-kT4c"
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it did not work because of a typo in the query ('orderbyChild' instead of 'orderByChild'). Thanks Firebase for not giving me any errors here:p

I am now indeed using .orderByChild(), .endAt() and .limitToLast() together, in a method chain. This makes sure that the query-conditions are executed in the correct order, where as querying this in a query object seems to execute these conditions in no particularly order.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using "[endat](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#endAt)" as well.

Have a look at [this tutorial](https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-data-structures-pagination-96c16ffdb5ca) for detailed instructions.

<strike>PS I'm on the phone, I'll reformat in a bit.</strike>

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Although it seems to be incorrect, endAt is not required, and would not work for me either. I don't have the ID of the '+10' message, since this isn't as simple as 'currentId +10'.

Comment: You're assuming how "endat" works and, sorry to say, you are wrong in that assumption. "endat" is an incredibly flexible tool and will allow you to select even more specific chunks of data. Not just the "next 10" or "currentId + 10". I suggest you have yet another look at the documentation and the tutorial provided to get a better understanding of the "endat" function as it might prove useful.